# How to enable new user by default in Joomla

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

Good morning. I am using Joomla 2.5 user registration form for user registration .when a new user created their new account the activation link will go to their registered  mail id .but the problem is when i see the newly registered user information in admin back end the new user is not Enabled . he is became Enabled after self activation only. How to make Enable new user by default after successful account creation . please give me some hint

thanks in advance .

Comment: check my answer given below
and this process same as in joomla 2.5 and 3.x but layout has changed but name of option are same so you can easily find this option in your joomla 2.5.

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). I recommend you asking your future [tag:joomla]-related questions there.

Comment: I think your problem has a working solution [here](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/7181/324).

Answer (score 0):

just follow these step and you`ll done that you want.

```
1. Login to admin panel 
2. Go to user manager
3. now select option for user manager
4. here is option for new user account activation
```

there are three option

```
  first is "none" means the newly user registered activate automatically
  second is "self" means newly user registered activate his/her account by itself
```

and

```
  third one is "admin" means admin activate newly user registered account
```

You follow this step and set it to None.

[DEMO IMAGE](http://awesomescreenshot.com/02344i1oa8)

[image]

Comment: this is ok , but my point is i wish that user need to activate their account by clicking activation link only ,but they need to enabled by default only .